# Question: if any supremum and the infimum of the set $\{x ∈\mathbb Q, 1<x<\sqrt{5}\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Question: Is there any supremum and the infimum of the set

$$ \{x ∈ \mathbb{Q} \mid 1<x<\sqrt{5} \}$$

my answer is $\sup= \sqrt 5$, $\inf=1$.

Am I right ?

So $\mathbb{Q}$ in this question doesn't matter?

Comment: This question is unclear. Do you mean "does there exist an infimum or supremum"?

Comment: $\inf = 1$ yes but $\sqrt{5} \notin \mathbb{Q}$, so the $\sup$ doesn't exist.

Comment: I and Henning made some edits to your post. Please try to follow them so you know how to format questions properly here.

Answer (score 2):

It matters whether you consider your set as a subset of the ordered set $(\mathbb Q,{\le})$ or the ordered set $(\mathbb R,{\le})$.

In the former case there is no supremum (because the supremum of a subset has to be an element of the ordered set you're considering); in the latter case $\sqrt 5$ is correct.

Lesson to learn: the terms "supremum" and "infimum" depends not only on what the set *is*, but also on what you consider it as a subset of.

Comment: but it doesn't matter  '<' or ' ≤ ' , right ?

Comment: @Karry: Yeah, that is just a question of which convention you're using for specifying an ordered set.